# Find the value of an element whose key is the largest of all keys smaller than a given key

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I know this kind of question has been answered before, but I can't understand why doesn't my code work right.

Added to title: If there is no key lesser than the given key, throw an exception.

Context: I'm implementing a map using a binary tree.

Implementation:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
Value BinStabloMapa<Key, Value>::prviManjiHelp(BSNode<Key, Value> *node, const Key&     key) const{   


if(node->_key > key){
    if(node->_left == 0) return node->_value;
return prviManjiHelp(node->_left, key);
}
else if(node->_key < key){
    if(node->_right == 0) return node->_value;
return prviManjiHelp(node->_right, key);
}
else if(node->_key == key){
    if(node->_left == 0) throw "JOK";
return node->_left->_value;
}
}



template<typename Key, typename Value>
Value BinStabloMapa<Key, Value>::prviManji(const Key& key) const {
if(_root == 0) throw "Map is empty";
return prviManjiHelp(_root, key);
}
```

And this is the text example:

```
BinStabloMapa <int, int> m;
m[5] = 5;
m[3] = 3;
m[8] = 8;
m[1] = 1;
m[2] = 2;
m[6] = 6;
cout << m.prviManji(5) << " " << m.prviManji(6);
cout << " " << m.prviManji(3) << " ";
cout << m.prviManji(12);
```

It should output 3,5,2,8, but instead it throws an exception. I've tried to find the cause and I've determined that it happens in the case when node->_key is equal to key.

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't include the code inserting values into your BST.

Comment: I can, but since this is an assignment which is sent online, it is autotested, and I believe(based on that it passed every test regarding insertion of elements), that is functions properly, but of course I can include it if needed.

Comment: The condition for the keys being equal isn't needed: if the sought key isn't smaller and isn't greater it must be equivalent!

Comment: Actually, `5` is found and an exception is thrown. This is what the code say does happen when the key is found! That said, I think the logic is still wrong: the biggest node smaller than key may be the parent of the leaf found.

Comment: When 5 is passed to the function it is compared to the root, and since it is equal, and has a left child, the largest element must be that child, so it returns 3. When I comment everything but the call with 5, it works properly